# $\det(A-\lambda I)$ or $\det(\lambda I - A)$?

Tags: linear-algebra, characteristic-polynomial

I have noticed that in many book, given a square matrix of order $n\times n$ called $A$, the characteristic polynomial is given by $\chi_A(\lambda)=\det(A-\lambda I)$. Some university lecturers instead propose to use $\chi_A(\lambda)=\det(\lambda I-A)$ as the characteristic polynomial. What is the advantage of considering $\chi_A(\lambda)=\det(\lambda I-A)$ instead of $\det(A-\lambda I)$?

Comment: It doesn't change anything since $\det(A-\lambda I)=(-1)^n\det(\lambda I-A)$.

Comment: Since the primary quantities of interest are the roots, I guess it dosent  make much of a difference

Comment: I always prefer the characteristic polynomial to be monic rather than with leading coefficient $(-1)^n$. No idea why some prefer $\det(A-\lambda I)$.

Comment: @Mark Here’s one reason. For students to calculate it, it lessens the computational complexity of keeping track of the product of lots of negatives (not to mention sloppy errors in negating all the entries of $A$).

Comment: @TedShifrin Then is better to use $\det(\lambda I-A)$?

Comment: No, the opposite. Think about what I just wrote. Unless there are mostly negative entries in $A$, in which case, yes.

Comment: @TedShifrin Thank you very much. Do you have understood the reason for the downvote on my question?

Comment: @TedShifrin Well, IMO having negative signs before terms of $x$ complicates it more than negative signs before numbers. In any case, you obviously have to compute it carefully.

Comment: It is presumably a duplicate, and some users of this site may be punishing you for not having searched before posting.

Comment: @Mark Odd psychology. But I speak from close to 40 years of exoerience teaching linear algebra.

Comment: @TedShifrin I thought that it was an original question and not a duplicate so I did not search.